# Matlab shortcut to start debugging?

Tags: matlab

Is there a possibility to have a MATLAB keyboard shortcut which would execute a certain `.m` file, instead of having to open the file first, and then start debugging it?

My project has many files (in different subfolders), and I always have to go back to `main.m` in order to start debugging.

Comment: Not sure about shortcuts, but literally typing the name of the `.m` file on the command line will execute it. Also, MATLAB has autocomplete, try pressing tab.

Answer (score 3):

You can make shortcuts in the MATLAB command window. If it's now shown yet, click on the <kbd>Layout</kbd> button in the <kbd>Environment</kbd> section of the <kbd>Home</kbd> tab, and then select `Shortcuts tab`.

In the <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> tab, click on <kbd>New shortcut</kbd>. Choose a label and whether you want to also show it in the `Quick Access` toolbar. The shortcut body should contain:

```
edit('main.m')      % ... or full path to it
dbstop in main at 1 % ... or any specific file/line number of your choosing
main                % start script/function to start debugging it
```

Not sure how to couple this to a keyboard shortcut, or if that is at all possible, but at least you can get there now in 1 click.

Comment: This is a great thing!

Comment: @danijel OK, what happens? Or doesn't happen?

Comment: It opens `main.m`, but then it says `Cannot find function main.` And there is no function `main`. I need to run the file, not function. Any idea?